# Breadcrumbs in Yii link is not correct

Tags: php, yii, breadcrumbs

I would like to use breadcrumb with variable.

I first look for the category (passed when the view is called)

```
$label = Category::model()->findByPk($category_id);  // I get the category record for a given category_id  (in this case, movies)
```

then I display the breadcrumbs with the following code

```
$this->breadcrumbs=array(
    $label->name => array('index','category_id='.$label->id),
    'Create',
);
```

as a display point of view it is correct, it displays

```
 Home » Movies » Create
```

but when I click on Movies  the url is

```
localhost/post/index.php/index?0=category_id=1
```

instead of

```
localhost/post/index.php/index?category_id=1
```

where does the 0= comes from ?

thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$label->name => array('index','category_id'=>$label->id),
```